# Writing to a memory file instead of file path

Tags: python, memorystream

Is it possible to supply a path to the buffer where to write the data instead of supplying a file path e.g. instead of `object.save("D:\filename.jpg")` supply it a path to memory buffer. I want to do this to avoid writing the image object data to file as `.JPG` and save it directly into memory so that I can have it in memory rather than loading it again from disk.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the `StringIO` library.

Comment: Wouldn't that really only be suitable for strings, and not raw binary, i.e. the kind of data you'd find in OP's JPG images?

Comment: @FrobberOfBits A string, in most languages including python, holds arbitrary binary data - it's not limited to printable characters.

Comment: Sure, in some sense all types are just bits...but strings seem to confuse the issue since if you're working with them  you're probably also thinking about issues such as character encoding, which is irrelevant for binary data.  Not saying it can't be done, just wondering why you'd turn to a library with "String" in the title to write binary data.

Comment: In Python 2, a string *is* binary data. In Python 3, BytesIO should be used instead.

Comment: For example I have an [image object](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm) in Python. Is it possible that I directly take this image object somehow and save all it's data into buffer?

Comment: "This module implements a file-like class, StringIO, that reads and writes a string buffer (also known as memory files)."

Comment: I tried it as the following `s = StringIO.StringIO()`
`d = im.save(s)` which invokes an error `AttributeError: StringIO instance has no attribute lower`. Here `im` is image object which apparently supports the use of StringIO like classes.

Comment: Memory buffers don't have paths, which apparently your image object requires.  If it can't be modified to take a file-like object instead, I think you're stuck.

Comment: From this [docs](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm) It can take it but I cannot figure out the attributeError.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a raw buffer of bytes to write to, use [bitstring](http://code.google.com/p/python-bitstring/).

```
>>> a = BitArray('0x1af')
>>> a.hex, a.bin, a.uint     # Different interpretations using properties
('1af', '000110101111', 431)
```

If you don't want a raw array of bits/bytes, then just keep your image object in memory.  It's basically the same thing as a file, just, as you say -- in memory not on disk.

Answer (score 0):

If `object.save` supports file-like objects, that means, objects, that have a write-method, you can provide the method with a `StringIO.StringIO` instance. It has the same interface as a normal file-object, but keeps its contents in memory.